# How to install an extension on Firefox while creating a webdriver through Robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, robotframework

I want to start a Firefox session with an installed extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/har-export-trigger/

My environment:

```
robotframework 3.2a1 
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 4.0.0a2
selenium 3.141.0
firefox 72.0
geckodriver 0.26.0
```

Here is my script:

```
${browser_options}  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].FirefoxProfile()  sys, selenium.webdriver

call method     ${browser_options}   add_extension  ${EXECDIR}/har_export_trigger-0.6.1-an+fx.xpi

create webdriver   Firefox   firefox_profile=${browser_options}
```

As a result, the extension is not installed (the steps just pass with no errors).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file is in the correct directory. Does it work when the filename does not have the `+` in the filename?

Comment: I've just tried the option with no `+` in the filename, the result is the same: extension is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me

## step1: open firefox

```
install certificate
install plugin
```

## step2:

```
firefox-> Help ->   More trouble information  -> Profile Directory

copy the path, my path is /Users/frank/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/dddddd.default-release
```

## step3: put the path in robot file

Open Browser          url         Firefox     ff_profile_dir=/Users/frank/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/dddddd.default-release